# Cannot write object to file in java

Tags: java, serialization, java-io

I have two class:

```
public abstract class GiaoDich{
 //variable and set/get method
    public abstract double calcualteMoney();
}

public class GiaoDichDat extends GiaoDich implements Serializable {
    public static List<GiaoDichDat> listGiaoDichDat = new ArrayList<>();
        //new value
    @Override
    public double calculatorMoney() {
    }

    public void getDatafromKeyboard() {
        //get data from keyboard
    }

    public double avgMoney() {
    }

    public void readFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        List<GiaoDichDat> lsttemp = new ArrayList<GiaoDichDat>();
        try
        {
            System.out.println("Doc du lieu tu file");
            ObjectInputStream obis = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream( "GiaoDichDat.text"));
            lsttemp = (List<GiaoDichDat>) obis.readObject();
            obis.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (GiaoDichDat get : lsttemp)
        {
            System.out.println(get.toString());
        }
    }

    public void saveFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("GiaoDichDat.text");
            ObjectOutputStream obos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            obos.writeObject(listGiaoDichDat);
            fos.close();
            obos.flush();
            System.out.println("Ghi du lieu thanh cong");
            obos.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

After I read data from terminal, I write to file it ok. But when I read again. It have no data.

Comment: Please show me code that you write and read data ?

Comment: Show me your write and read file.

Comment: public void readFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException,
   ClassNotFoundException {
  List<GiaoDichDat> lsttemp = new ArrayList<GiaoDichDat>();
  try {
   System.out.println("Doc du lieu tu file");
   ObjectInputStream obis = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(
     "GiaoDichDat.text"));
   lsttemp = (List<GiaoDichDat>) obis.readObject();
   obis.close();
  } catch (IOException ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }
  for (GiaoDichDat get : lsttemp) {
   System.out.println(get.toString());
  }
 }

Comment: public void saveFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
  try {
   FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("GiaoDichDat.text");
   ObjectOutputStream obos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
   obos.writeObject(listGiaoDichDat);
   fos.close();
   obos.flush();
   System.out.println("Ghi du lieu thanh cong");
   obos.close();
  } catch (IOException ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

Comment: you should add it into your post

Comment: sorry, I can't add them to my post :(

Comment: 'Cannot write' and 'have no data' are not problem descriptions. Serialized data is not text and should not be saved in files called .text. Neither [tag:streamreader] nor [tag:streamwriter] has anything to do with this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read and write object with `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream`, all of your Objects need to implement `Serializable` but your parent class fails to do so.

Comment: The parent class doesn't need to implement `Serializable.` Consider `java.lang.Object`.  The OP's parent class is abstract and contains no state.

Comment: I don't understand, when I change it and no change anymore, I can see output data.

Comment: the GiaoDich class is a abstract class and it have many private variable, set/get method. Child class using these property.

Comment: @Sakura1108 Not according to the code you posted. If you want your undisclosed private variables in the parent class to be serialized, then of course you must make it `Serializable.` But none of this was disclosed in your question.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you must have ignored an exception that was thrown:

```
fos.close();
```

Don't close this.

```
obos.flush();
```

This should have caused an `IOException` because of the prior close. In any case you should remove it, as `obos.close()` causes a `flush()` anyway.

```
System.out.println("Ghi du lieu thanh cong");
obos.close();
```

This is the only close you need.

There is no point in catching `IOException` in these methods, as they are already declared to throw it, and the callers need to know about any exceptions. Remove the catch blocks.

Comment: I add it but still bug

Comment: Still *same* bug? You're not very forthcoming here.